# Using local perl variables in shell command

Tags: regex, perl, shell, remote-access, openssh

I am trying to run a remote find command but I have to pass it local variables whose value I get from command line arguments from user. But, I am getting an "undefined variable" error. I am doing something like :

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
#I am getting a part of the $path and $pattern from command line
#I have to look for $pattern at the $path
my @files = $ssh->capture(q(find $path -name $pattern) );
```

This command runs fine when I give the exact path and pattern but I get error  when I replace it with variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
q(find $path -name $pattern)
```

This is the literal string `find $path -name $pattern`, dollar signs and all.

Perl has several different kinds of quotes. `""` will interpolate variables (ie. replace them with their values), `''` will not. `q()` is another way to write `''`. You want `qq()`.

See [Quote and Quote-Like Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for more info.

Comment: yes thank you for your reply. Now, it is not giving me an error but it is unable to get the matched patterns. That is, I am getting a "find:no match" when I store the same pattern in a variable but is running when I use value of pattern directly in command.
Thanks again :)

Comment: my $pattern = "*40786*";

    #This runs when I write  my @files = $ssh->capture2(qq(find /u1/temp  -name "*40786*") ); 
#but returns not found when I use variable $pattern

Sorry if its a silly question. I am new to perl and couldn't find an explanation elsewhere.

Comment: @emma That should work. Without the surrounding code, I can't tell you what's wrong. I'd suggest you ask a new question and provide a complete program that doesn't work.